# pymc3 , product of probability distributions

Tags: python, statistics, bayesian, pymc3

I have a transactional dataset that I would like to model so that I can do an A/B test.

The model is:

`S(x) = T * V(x)`

where `T` is the probability that a user buys something and `V(x)` is the probability that a purchase will have log value `x`

`T` can be modeled as `pm.Bernoulli` and `V(x)` can be modeled as a `pm.Normal`

Now I would have thought that one could do:

```
conv  = pm.Bernoulli("conversion",p)
value = pm.Normal("value", mu, sd)
val = pm.Deterministic('name',conv*value, observed=data)
```

But that doesn't work. How should I go about this? I feel it should be really easy.